# cannot get POST request on express

Tags: node.js, express

I can't get any `POST` requests with the express framework.

This is my code

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set("view engine","ejs")

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");

});
app.post("/addfriend", function(req, res){
   res.send("you have reached the post route succesfully");
});
app.get("/friends", function(req, res){
    var friends =["lara","tommy","miranda","faith","locas"];

    res.render("friends",{friends : friends});
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

any suggestion please.

Comment: if you check your browser console for errors when you send the request, do you get anything mentioning CORS or "cross origin..." perhaps?

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. What do you mean with 'can't get any POST requests'. Are you getting an error? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: you need to use a tool like "postman" to send a post request to your server. it is not possible to send post requests directly from the browser URL. unless you have a form that submits to that URL using POST method.

Comment: you'll get better answer if you edit your question to include the steps you are performing to access the POST "addfriend" route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observations.

1)You are missing body parser for your app.js ( if in future you want to read form data).

just add this to your app,js

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Wherever you are using trying to send post request for example a HTML form or a button does it have correct route, it should match with this post route `/addfriend`.

2. Browser always send get request to server from browser, to specifically send post request use postman, curl or a HTML form.
   If you are using postman try this https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#sending-body-data

For the difference between get and post follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)

Edit :-
Http post request means :- "The HTTP POST method sends data to the server. The type of the body of the request is indicated by the Content-Type header."

get request :- "The HTTP GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only be used to request data (they shouldn't include data)."

Comment: Why did you edit the question to mention postman? There was no indication that postman was used. I reverted that change, but thought it was strange. OP also is not reading any bodies in the sample code, so there's no reason to assume that this is the problem.

Comment: the POST route works only when i submit the form because when i click the link the browser work with it as a GET request how can i fix that except using postman!

Comment: @Evert the question before your edit included postman by OP :), He is not reading nay bodies yet i posted this as an observation for his future usecases.

Comment: @Eman for confirmation you want Post route should work when you click the link?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra ah it wasn't you, but it wasn't OP either! A random person adding 'postman'. Weird!